# Android Pubnub One to One chat

Tags: android, pubnub

I want to implement the Online/Offline/IsTying functionality using the pubnub library in android. For this i created the Pubnub connection.

```
//create the pubnub connection

 PNConfiguration configuration = new PNConfiguration();
            configuration.setPublishKey(PUBNUB_PUBLISH_KEY);
            configuration.setSubscribeKey(PUBNUB_SUBSCRIBE_KEY);
            configuration.setLogVerbosity(PNLogVerbosity.BODY);
            configuration.setConnectTimeout(100000);
            configuration.setSubscribeTimeout(31000);
            configuration.setHeartbeatNotificationOptions(PNHeartbeatNotificationOptions.ALL);
            configuration.setPresenceTimeoutWithCustomInterval(120,59);
            configuration.setPresenceTimeout(120);
            mPubNub = new PubNub(configuration);
```

And after that i set the subscriber callback to the listener

```
**strong text**

private SubscribeCallback subscribeCallback = new SubscribeCallback() {

        @Override
        public void status(PubNub pubnub, PNStatus status) {
            Log.d("Chat", "status() called with: pubnub = [" + pubnub + "], status = [" + status + "]");
            if (status.getOperation() != null) {
                switch (status.getOperation()) {

                    // let's combine unsubscribe and subscribe handling for ease of use
                    case PNSubscribeOperation:
                    case PNUnsubscribeOperation:
                        Toast.makeText(ChatAppService.this, "Status : " + status.getOperation().name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // note: subscribe statuses never have traditional
                        // errors, they just have categories to represent the
                        // different issues or successes that occur as part of subscribe
                        switch (status.getCategory()) {
                            case PNConnectedCategory:
                                // this is expected for a subscribe, this means there is no error or issue whatsoever
                                Toast.makeText(ChatAppService.this, "Status : " + status.getCategory(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case PNReconnectedCategory:
                                // this usually occurs if subscribe temporarily fails but reconnects. This means
                                // there was an error but there is no longer any issue
                                Toast.makeText(ChatAppService.this, "Status : " + status.getCategory(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap();
                                map.put("State","Online");
                                pubnub.setPresenceState().channels(Arrays.asList(Constants.GLOBAL_CHANNEL)).state(map).uuid(pubnub.getConfiguration().getUuid());
                                break;
                            case PNDisconnectedCategory:
                                // this is the expected category for an unsubscribe. This means there
                                // was no error in unsubscribing from everything
                                Toast.makeText(ChatAppService.this, "Status : " + status.getCategory(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                HashMap<String,String> mapOffline = new HashMap();
                                mapOffline.put("State","Offline");
                                pubnub.setPresenceState().channels(Arrays.asList(Constants.GLOBAL_CHANNEL)).state(mapOffline).uuid(pubnub.getConfiguration().getUuid());
                                break;
                            case PNTimeoutCategory:
                                HashMap<String,String> mapTimeout = new HashMap();
                                mapTimeout.put("State","Offline");
                                pubnub.setPresenceState().channels(Arrays.asList(Constants.GLOBAL_CHANNEL)).state(mapTimeout).uuid(pubnub.getConfiguration().getUuid());
                                pubnub.reconnect();
                                break;
                            case PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory:
                                // this is usually an issue with the internet connection, this is an error, handle appropriately
                                Toast.makeText(ChatAppService.this, "Status : " + status.getCategory(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                pubnub.reconnect();
                                break;
                            case PNAccessDeniedCategory:
                                // this means that PAM does allow this client to subscribe to this
                                // channel and channel group configuration. This is another explicit error
                                Toast.makeText(ChatAppService.this, "Status : " + status.getCategory(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            default:
                                // More errors can be directly specified by creating explicit cases for other
                                // error categories of `PNStatusCategory` such as `PNTimeoutCategory` or `PNMalformedFilterExpressionCategory` or `PNDecryptionErrorCategory`
                        }
                        break;
                    case PNHeartbeatOperation:
                        // heartbeat operations can in fact have errors, so it is important to check first for an error.
                        // For more information on how to configure heartbeat notifications through the status
                        // PNObjectEventListener callback, consult <link to the PNCONFIGURATION heartbeart config>
                        if (status.isError()) {
                            // There was an error with the heartbeat operation, handle here
                        } else {
                            // heartbeat operation was successful
                        }
                        break;
                    default: {
                        // Encountered unknown status type
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // After a reconnection see status.getCategory()
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void message(PubNub pubnub, PNMessageResult message) {
            //TODO: If App open: Save to database and broadcast for database change else show Notification

        }

        @Override
        public void presence(PubNub pubnub, PNPresenceEventResult presence) {
            Log.d("chat", "presence() called with: pubnub = [" + pubnub + "], presence = [" + presence + "]");
        }
    };`
```

Finally the issue is that when i leave the group then no presence callback is coming.I should get the event of leave the channel with user state so that i can remove the user from the online user's list.

for unsubscribing the group

```
pubnub.unsubscribe().channels(Arrays.asList(channel)).execute()
```

when i subscribe the channel then presence callback calls three time
1. event : join
2. event : state-changes
3. event : leave

I am not getting how to handle this scenario in Android. Please help me i am stucking in this problem from last three days.

Comment: I am noticing a similar behavior. Did you get a fix for this?

Comment: these two lines do the same thing. You can eliminate one of them.             configuration.setPresenceTimeoutWithCustomInterval(120,59);
            configuration.setPresenceTimeout(120);

Comment: Are you using two clients to test or one. If one, then you can't assume you will get your own leave event. But still not sure about the scenario you have. Can you enable logging and reproduce: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/pubnub-android-sdk-troubleshooting-guide

Comment: Did you give up on this? Let us know if you still need assistance. Try sending to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com)